# Collision with foreign key using same related_name

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

Using peewee, we have created de following Model:

```
class Interview(BaseModel):
    iid = PrimaryKeyField()
    day = DateField()
    start = TimeField()
    end = TimeField()
    mentor_id = ForeignKeyField(Mentor, related_name='mentor_interview')
    reserved = BooleanField(default=False)
```

We also have other Models, but we never reference to the other Mentor model as a foreign key anywhere, just here. I've found, that if we would use 2 foreign keys, referring to the same Model, without using related names, that could cause the error, what we have, but we are not doing that. So the error is the following:

```
AttributeError: Foreign key: interview.mentor_id related name "mentor_interview"
collision with foreign key using same related_name.
```

We are not using the related name anywhere, just here. What are we doing wrong?